# Inserting the same HTML Form element into multiple modals when shown, but validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am developing a one page website using HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4 and jQuery. I also use [jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html) for form validation.

The problem is that I have several Bootstrap modals having different text content that must includes the same form in their bodies:

```
<div id="modal-1" class="modal fade my-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>MODAL TITLE 1</h5> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>MODAL CONTENT 1</p>

                <div class="form-container">
                    <!-- SAME FORM FOR ALL MODALS -->
                    <form id="myForm-1" action="">
                    ...
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
<div id="modal-n" class="modal fade my-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>MODAL TITLE N</h5> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>MODAL CONTENT N</p>

                <div class="form-container">
                    <!-- SAME FORM FOR ALL MODALS -->
                    <form id="myForm-n" action="">
                    ...
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found a solution that works perfectly for inserting the form when modals shown using jQuery, but the form validation doesn't work at all:

```
var $myForm = $("<form id="myForm" action="">...</form>");

$(".my-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {    
    $(this).find(".form-container").append($myForm);
});
```

This is the jQuery validation code:

```
$.validate({
    form: "#myForm",
    modules: "file",
    borderColorOnError: ""
});
```

Is there a way to make it work just by using jQuery?
I am planning to use Laravel for multi-language support, is it better to use Blade Template to achieve that?
Or other sort of javascript templating engines like Mustache, Handlebars...?

Thanks for you replies.

**ps:** I am a Java Spring developer and I am new to Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make it work just by using jQuery?

Sure!. The thing is that `#myForm` doesn't exist when `$.validate({` is parsed. So I suggest you to make it exist... By placing in in the body.

```
<div id="modal-1" class="modal fade my-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5>MODAL TITLE 1</h5> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>MODAL CONTENT 1</p>

        <div class="form-container">
          <!-- SAME FORM FOR ALL MODALS -->
          <form id="myForm-1" action="">
            ...
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
<div id="modal-n" class="modal fade my-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5>MODAL TITLE N</h5> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>MODAL CONTENT N</p>

        <div class="form-container">
          <!-- SAME FORM FOR ALL MODALS -->
          <form id="myForm-n" action="">
            ...
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form id="myForm" action="">...</form>
```

Just hide it with CSS:

```
#myForm{
  display:none;
}
```

Then "move" your form into the modal.

```
$(".my-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {    
  $(this).find(".form-container").append($("#myForm").show());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Louys, your solution looks great, does the show() function will make the form shown in both modal and body? just asking before testing it.

Comment: It will show in the modal only... Since the form will litterally move there. It's not a duplicated form.